# In Meteor, how/where do I write code that triggers when an authorized user has logged in?

Tags: javascript, meteor, admin, roles

New to Meteor, I'm using the `alanning:roles` package to handle roles.

I've managed to be able to only publish a collection when a user is logged in, when the page is first refreshed.

```
Meteor.publish('col', function(){
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
        console.log('authed');
        return Sessions.find({});
    } else {
        console.log('not auth');
        // user unauthorized
        this.stop();
        return;
    }
});
```

Logging out kills access to the collection (I'm using mongol to see). Logging back in after logging out, or logging in from a logged out state when the page is first loaded, will not give me access.

The webapp I'm trying to build is something like an ticketing system. I'm trying to be secure, so no unnecessary publishing if the user is not authorized.

What I'm trying to do is, get ticket information submitted from users from a collection, and display it on the client screen (as long as the client is authorized first). Maybe a better way to handle this is to force a refresh (how do I do that?) after a user change so unauthorized users are "kicked" out? And render all relevant data from the private collection right after the user is authorized?

Comment: when do you do the subscription on the client? I am suspecting that stopping the subscription serverside would require you to rerun subscribe after the login.

Comment: I have a Subs.js file inside the client folder, which contains just one line, `Meteor.subscribe('col');`.  Is there a better practice for subscriptions?

Comment: Its fine i guess. What i was trying to say is if you do stop the subscription on the server than there is no subscription. Even after the login happened there is still no subscription, unless you rerun the client side subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to get what I want for now with helpers...

In my `./client/Subs.js` file:

```
Meteor.subscribe('col');

Template.NewTicket.helpers({ // match the template name
    // move this into method later, not secure because on client??
    isAdmin() {
        console.log('is admin.');
        console.log(Meteor.userId());
        Meteor.subscribe('col');
        return Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin');
    },

});
```

and then somewhere in my template file `./client/partials/NewTicket.html`:

```
<template name="NewTicket">
  {{#if isAdmin}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

to trigger the check? I'm 99% sure theres a better way.